# Is there a way to know in SqlServer 2016+ which locks a table held in the past?

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with timeouts in production caused by transaction locks and cannot reproduce it. I'd need to know which transaction (an statement would be useful to identify the process) is blame of the block.

I tried with the information of who_sp2 and other tables like the statement below, but are only useful while the block is being held, not after.

```
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tActive
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions tSession
    ON (tSession.transaction_id = tActive.transaction_id) LEFT OUTER
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS tExec
    ON tSession.session_id = tExec.session_id LEFT OUTER
JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS tRequest
```

Comment: Look at capturing the "Blocked Process Report" to get blocking info

Comment: Transaction related DMVs return only active transactions. So you need to have a mechanism to periodically collect the data that can be used for later analysis. A common practice is to use a third party monitoring tool connected to production DB that collects this and other details to later analysis. Another workaround is to use the `sp_whoisactive` (from http://whoisactive.com/). This SP is much better than sp_who2 and have many options to display detailed information about the transactions and blocking/locking details. And also settings to collect the details to a table for later analysis

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Charlieface is it feasible or , in other words, a good idea to keep that kind of traces running in productionn for a long-time?

Comment: Blocked process report is OK, you just need to make sure it's on a long enough timer that it doesn't keep getting triggered. XEvents in general is much lighter than the old Profiler, especially if you use the right `WHERE` filters